# show that for $n\in \Bbb N, n >3$, $0< \sum_{m=n+1} \frac{1}{m!} < \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

show that for $n\in \Bbb N, n >3$

$0< \sum_{m=n+1} \frac{1}{m!} < \frac{1}{n!}$

For my work so far: I really don't have a good idea of how to approach this problem. I was thinking that $\sum_{m=n+1} \frac{1}{m!}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{m(m+1)...}$ but it doesn't lead me anywhere. I was also thinking that it might have to do with the exponential function where $exp(x)=\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$. But I can't quite relate.

Comment: Hint: multiply by $n!$, leave the first term alone and from second term on keep only the last 2 factors in the denominator and telescope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(n+k)!=(n+k)(n+k-1)\cdots (n+1)n!>(2)(2)\cdots (2)n!$ where there are $k$ $2$'s. Now use the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{k}}=1$.